# hibernate naming strategy doesn't work for spring data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, naming

I am going to add the following class:

```
package my.package;

@Entity
public class ExceptionalCalendarDay {
  ...
}
```

*Respective table name in database: `tExceptionalCalendarDay`

and following `entityManagerFactory` configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.package"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myUnitName"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">my.util.NamingStrategy</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${db.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">${db.use_generated_keys}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">${db.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults}</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

                <!-- jdbc connection properties -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">${db.isolation}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

naming strategy:

```
public class NamingStrategy extends DefaultNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String classToTableName(String qualifiedName) {
        String tableName = super.classToTableName(qualifiedName);
        return "t" + tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public String propertyToColumnName(String propertyName) {
        return WordUtils.capitalize(super.propertyToColumnName(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and I have following repository:

```
public interface BusinessDayRepository extends JpaRepository<ExceptionalCalendarDay, Date> {
    List<ExceptionalCalendarDay> findAll();
}
```

If into database table calls as `ExceptionalCalendarday` all works good but if I rename it as `tExceptionalCalendarday` - this doesn't work:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'dbo.ExceptionalCalendarDay'.
```

strange.

What the reason?

### P.S.

If add name to `Entity` annotation

```
@Entity(name = "tExceptionalCalendarDay")
```

all works good

Comment: Please update with spring and hibernate versions that you are using ?